# c# Word COMException (0x800A11FD) when adding a new field to document

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-addins, comexception

I want to add a new field to the Fields list in the document. I am calling `Doc.Unprotect("secret");` to be able to add the new field because the selected fieldText is in a `protected` document. When the `Doc.Fields.Add` method is called I get the undefined COMException below.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

```
Doc.Unprotect("secret");
Doc.SetDocProperty(fieldKey, fieldText);
W.Field field = Doc.Fields.Add(app.Selection.Range, W.WdFieldType.wdFieldDocProperty, fieldKey, true);
```

Exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A11FD): Command is not available. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Fields.Add(Range
>   Range, Object& Type, Object& Text, Object& PreserveFormatting)

Comment: Have a lookk at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786644/this-method-or-property-is-not-available-because-a-document-window-is-not-active Could possibly help you. Troubleshooting `COMExceptions` is alway terrible :(

Comment: If I do not protect the word document and try to add the field, everything works as it should. It seems that the Unprotect method call is unnecessary. Maybe it is something with app.Selection.Range, maybe it is not allowed to add fields with when doc Range is protected?!

Comment: COM exceptions that start with 0x800A are errors generated by the app itself.  So you want to google "word error 4605", lotsa hits.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a variable instead of the string and if that doesn't work then make sure the document is actually protected. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.unprotect?view=vsto-2017):

> Avoid using hard-coded passwords in your applications. If a password is required in a procedure, request the password from the user, store it in a variable, and then use the variable in your code.
>
> If the document is not protected, an exception is thrown.

Comment: I am using an auto generated password wich is in a readonly variable in my code.